# Electrical lights stay on and headlights won't turn on

Tags: electrical, nissan, headlight, lights, sentra

I have an 1996 nissan sentra and my headlights won't come on and the park lights,tail lights, stay on even when the car is off and key removed as well the fuses are good and there is no headlight relay what could the problem be thx!!!